# shouldStartLoadWithRequest does not get called on html button click in uiwebview

Tags: ios

I am loading html content in `UIWebView`. Now, when I click on a button the delegate `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` does not get called.

Below is the structure of the html button in uiwebview.

```
 input id="proceedInstructions" class="addonBtns" type="button" value="Start" onClick="loadProvider()"
```

But, `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` never gets called when I click on the Start button. Please help.

Comment: What does `loadProvider()` do? Have you set your class to be the delegate of the web view?

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the UIWebViewDelegate?

Comment: it sounds like something like that.. maybe the button has no target (not plugged to an IBAction)

Comment: Yes i am setting it in nib properly. WebViewDidfinishload calls but shouldStartLoadWithRequest does not get called

Comment: the button cannot be plugged to an IBAction because it's a html button in webview

Answer (score 0):

`shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is called when a new webpage is loaded.
Check your controller is the delegate (`UIWebViewDelegate`) of you `UIWebView` and that the `loadProvider()' javascript code called by your HTML button does load a page.